# No service for type 'CommanderContext' has been registered

Tags: .net-core, graphql, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET 5.0 and HotChoclate framework to create a GraphQL API.
Below is my ConfigureServices Method

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<CommanderContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("default"));
            });
            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                    .AddQueryType<Query>()
                    .AddMutationType<Mutation>()
                    .AddFiltering()
                    .AddSorting()
                    .AddProjections();
        }
```

To resolve the concurrency issues. I am using AddPooledDbContextFactory() method.
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/integrations/entity-framework.

Below is my Configure Method

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                InitializeDatabase(app);
            }
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGraphQL();
            });
        }

        private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CommanderContext>().Database.Migrate(); //Here I get the exception.
        }
```

Since the application is in development, I want the migrations to be automatically applied to the database.

But when I try and get instance of my context class in InitializeDatabase() method, I get the above exception.

Now I have a little understanding that instead of getting a single instance my context class I am getting back a pool of context class.

My Question is: **How to I automatically apply the migrations to my database.**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AddPooledDbContextFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.addpooleddbcontextfactory?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddPooledDbContextFactory%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0) method registers [`IDbContextFactory<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.idbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-5.0) instead the `DbContext` itself, that's why you can't use `GetRequiredService<TContext>`. Instead, you should retrieve the factory, use it to obtain `TContext` instance, do your work and then `Dispose` it (which in fact will return it to the pool). You can't rely on DI to do that for you because it is not resolved (thus not maintained) by the DI system, but from another abstraction (called factory pattern).

Something like this:

```cs
using var context = scope.ServiceProvider
    .GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<CommanderContext>>()
    .CreateDbContext();

context.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Doesn't prepending the assignment with `using` as you've done automatically dispose of the context?

Comment: @JonathanE.Landrum Yes, it does. That's part of the answer - *not* obtaining the `DbContext` from DI, in which case you *must not* dispose it, but use factory to *create* new one, in which case you *must* dispose it (with `using` or `try/finally`)

Comment: ok, that makes more sense now. thank you for the further clarification!